# Having multiple servers talk to each other in rocket test environment

Tags: rust, rocket

I have a situation where I want two servers to talk to each other in a test. As in Server A is triggered and then sends a message to Server B.

I can send requests to both Server A and B individually, but when I try to get Server A to talk to B at 0.0.0.0:[port] I get `ConnectionRefused, message: "Connection refused"`

edit I wrote out an example

https://github.com/JesseAbram/rocket_testing_issue

Answer (score 1):

The Rocket `Client` used for testing uses a function called `launch_local()` which starts the server without binding to any listening addresses. So instead of using that, I spun up servers as normal in separate threads so they were not blocking, and then used [reqwest](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest) to talk to them.